# Backup and restore database using T-Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, backup, restore

I am trying to copy 'Development' database and create a new database called 'Testing'.
For backup, I have used the below query and it worked fine.

```
BACKUP DATABASE Development TO DISK = 'Development15feb2022.bak'
```

For restoring I have used the below query which is giving some errors like 'Development.mdf cannot be overwritten. It is being used by database 'Development'.

```
RESTORE DATABASE Testing FROM DISK = 'Development15feb2022.bak'
```

I have done some googling and came to know that I need to use MOVE for logical file and logs.
But I am not sure if that applies to my scenario.
I want both Development and Testing working independently and storing each logs respectively.
Can anyone clarify please?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/254796/restore-a-database-with-a-different-name-on-the-same-server ?

Comment: Why don't you just use [`DBCC CLONEDATABASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-clonedatabase-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @Serg . But that does not clarify my doubt. Does using 'Move' command effect my Development database?

Comment: @Bin The MOVE option affects the database to which you are restoring, not the original database from which you made the backup. So no - this will not affect the database "Development" - only the database "Testing". For future reference, always post the complete error message that you encounter - don't abbreviate it or simplify it.

Answer (score 1):

When restoring, by default, SQL Server create the database file at the same place and name as the original backuped database.

If you are doing a copy of the database on the same SQL instance, this will raise an error, because files already exists. So you must move the file to another directory or give another name to the file, which is done by the MOVE option of the RESTORE statement.

Prior to that, you must ask which files constitues the original database, by executing the Transact SQL command :

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'the path and file of my sql backup'
```

Then you will have to follow the MOVE syntax, which is just:

```
MOVE 'logical file name' TO 'new path and/or new file name'
```